# SQL Query IF EXISTS not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following sql query that I want to run with PHP.
Why doesn't it work?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM content WHERE site_id ='". $id ."') BEGIN
UPDATE content SET
titel = '". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[0])) ."',
content = '". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[1])) ."'
WHERE site_id ='". $id ."'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO content (site_id, titel, content)
VALUES (
'". $id ."',
'". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[0])) ."',
'". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[1])) ."'
)
END
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM content WHERE site_id ='1') BEGIN UPDATE content SET tit' at line 1

Comment: Why not use [INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Edit your question with error details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that site_id is a unique key in your table. Use the solution proposed by @Saty

```
INSERT INTO content (site_id, titel, content)
VALUES (
  '". $id ."',
  '". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[0])) ."',
  '". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[1])) ."'
)
ON DUPLICATE UPDATE 
  titel = '". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[0])) ."',
  content = '". htmlentities($connect->real_escape_string($data[1])) ."';
```